# Allow different roles to access the index page

Tags: php, symfony, security

This is the `security.yaml` :

```
security:
  access_control:
    - ...
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

### Expected behavior:

Allowing every user (`isGranted('ROLE_USER')` upon creation) to access the index page routed in `@Route("/","index")`, and denying them from accessing any page (not mentioned in a previous access control) with a route like `"/example"`, unless they have the `ROLE_ADMIN` role.

### Actual behavior:

Allows every user (with role `ROLE_USER`) to access any page (not mentioned in a previous access control) with a route like `"/example"`

### Notes

- Since 'Only the first access control that matches will be used', I guess that the route `/` is considered part of `/*` in Symfony, and even though that explains the behavior. It still doesn't solve how to make the index page `/` accessible by some users yet restrict access to pages like `/example`.
- I could restrict access to every page with a route like `/example` with    `- { path: ^/example, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }`, but that doesn't look clean since it may cause security vulnerabilities later on.

Comment: IIRC, `^/$` will match with the index.

Comment: Are all site vistors required to login?

Comment: @geoB yes they are. Do you suggest that I redirect them to a different route upon logging in ? If so, I tried to but the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security.html#roles) do not seem to tell enough on how to.

Comment: thank you @A.L . I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @*A.L* said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533674/allow-different-roles-to-access-the-index-page?noredirect=1#comment128130039_72533674), this worked for me:

```
security:
  access_control:
    - ...
    - { path: ^/$, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

---

However, if you think there is a better way to achieve the same result, your answer would be appreciated.